# Show that this integral is convergent for n in natural numbers:

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Is $\int_{0}^{∞} \frac{x^{2n−1}}{(1 + x^2)^{n+3}}dx$ convergent for n in natural numbers? [I've already found the indefinite integral which is that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7vwS.png) but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: I'm quite sure your indefinite integral is wrong. To prove convergence, just find an equivalent of the integrand when $x\to+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** observe that for $x \to +\infty$, we have
$$\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(1+x^2)^{n+3}} \sim \frac{1}{x^{2n+6 - 2n +1}}=\frac{1}{x^7}$$

Comment: But this integral does not converge from $0$ to $∞$, does it?

Comment: Actually, it does. As you can see using the asymptotic test. I believe the indefinite integral you provided is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_1^{\infty} \frac {x^{2n-1}} {(1+x^{2})^{n+3}}dx \leq \int_1^{\infty} \frac {x^{2n-1}} {(x^{2})^{n+3}}dx=\int_1^{\infty} x^{-7}dx <\infty$. Can you show that $\int_0^{1} \frac {x^{2n-1}} {(1+x^{2})^{n+3}}dx<\infty$?

Comment: Could it be $\int_0^{1} \frac {x^{2n-1}} {(1+x^{2})^{n+3}}dx \leq \int_0^{1} \frac {x^{2n-1}} {(1)^{n+3}}dx=number$?

Comment: @GerardNavarro Yes. But you can also use the fact any continuous function on $[0,1]$ is integrable.